# jQuery replace image in iframe

Tags: jquery

So i have an iframe named templateiframe in the iframe i have an image editButton1. I want to replace the image from the main page but cannot seem to get it to work. I got the main page to update text in the iframe I'm thinking my jquery is wrong. Can anyone help me out?

```
$("#templateiframe").contents().find("#editButton1").attr('src',('images/btn_edit_b.gif'));
```

Oh if I run this code on the iframe the image gets swapped

```
$('#editButton1').attr('src',('images/btn_edit_b.gif'));
```

Comment: Got it needed to use $(window).load(function(){